# Decision tree probabilities

Tags: probability, economics, decision-theory, decision-trees

I am solving the following decision problem. I formulated the problem into the tree OK but am unsure of what the probabilities along the branches are. i.e. how do I go from, for example, $P(H_1 \cap H_2)$ to $P(H_2)$?

---

Tom has 100, 000 savings and he uses 50, 000 to buy a house

The probability of having highly dangerous fires in year 1 and moderately dangerous ones in year 2 in the area where the house resides is equal to 0.25. The probability of having moderately dangerous fires in year 1 and highly dangerous ones in year 2 is equal to 0.15. The probability of having highly dangerous fires in year 1 and year 2 is equal to 0.2. The probability of having moderately dangerous fires in year 1 and year 2 is equal to 0.4.

Let $H_k$ be the event of having a highly dangerous fire in year $k$ and $M_K$ be the event of having a moderately dangerous fire in year in $k$.

So we have: $P(H_1 \cap M_2)=0.25$, $P(M_1 \cap H_2)=0.15$, $P(H_1 \cap H_2)=0.2$ and $P(M_1 \cap M_2)=0.4$

If a highly dangerous fire happens during the first year, then Tom insures the house for year 2. In any case, and independently of the previous events, Tom insures the house for year 3.

Insurance costs start at 500 for year 1. In each year this rises by 200 if there was a highly dangerous fire the year before. If a moderate fire, it reduces by 100.

---

> Draw and solve the decision tree , maximising Tom's residual savings

Here is my decision tree:

[image: Tree]

Hopefully I have the nodes and insurance costs (written in red) correct. Although I am unsure how to calculate the probabilities along the branches. How do we use the given probabilities of the form $P(A \cap B)$ to find $P(A)$ etc?

Thank you for your help

Comment: In your diagram, the node "Fire Type (year 1)" has a branch labelled M going to "Insure in year 2". However, the problem says that Tom insures the house in year 2 only if a highly dangerous fire occurs in year 1.

Comment: I disagree. It says "If a highly dangerous fire happens during the first year, then Tom insures the house for year 2". It does not specify for the case of a moderate fire happening. Hence, I put a decision node representing Tom's choice to insure after a moderate fire

Comment: But I don't understand why the branch labelled H from the "Fire Type (Year 1)" does not lead to a "insure in year 2" node. To be clear, in both my comments I am referring to the "yes" part of the tree starting from "insure in year 1".

Comment: So, Tom has chosen to insure for the first year. If a highly dangerous fire happens, we are told that we have no choice to insure - we have to insure. Hence there is a decision node after this event. If, however, a moderate fire happens, we get to choose whether to insure (since we have not been told that we must insure), so there is a decision node after this to reflect this choice

Comment: OK. I misunderstood your diagram. You don't need the individual probabilities $P(H_i)$. Each of the leaves of your tree correspond to one of the events $(H_1, H_2), (H_1, M_2), (M_1, H_2), (M_1, M_2)$. So, you can probably just put the probabilities corresponding to those events at the leaves.

Comment: aren't all these events independent.. so the values on branches will be of the form $P(A)$ as opposed to $P(A|B)$ or $P(A \cap B)$?

Comment: To reach each leaf on the tree, all the events on the branch leading to the leaf must happen. So, to reach the leaf the events on that branch must all happen. That is, both the events must happen. However, it's strange that there is no mention of the difference in damage to the house between a highly dangerous vs moderately dangerous fire.

Comment: Yes but the conditional aspect is covered by the backwards induction at the end surely?

Comment: The value on the first branch is $P(A)$. The value on the following branch is $P(B|A)$. $P(A\bigcap B) = P(B\mid A)\;P(A)$ is true regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ are independent. If they are independent, then $P(B\mid A) = P(B)$

Comment: Alright thanks, I will have another attempt at the question